# How to make a secure connection between application and server

Tags: php, security, flutter, ssl

I've searched a lot and wasn't able to find an exact answer to this question.
I have a flutter app that communicates with my own server. My server returns data related to the user, submits their order, returns their transaction history, etc. I'm using firebase in my app. It authenticates the user and I use the user's UID as a token to make sure whoever is communicating with the server has signed in  in the app (users can't figure out their UIDs as far as i know). In addition I've added certificate pinning.

Is this all that I can do to secure these communications? I want to make sure whoever is contacting the server is doing so from the app (that's why I'm using the uid). Is t his the right way to authenticate the user? What other security measurements can I take?(PHP files with flutter app).

Comment: `users can't figure out their UIDs as far as i know` If the UID is on the users' end device, they *will* be able to figure it out. Once something is on the User client machine it can no longer be assured.

Comment: So what do you recommend instead in order to ensure a secure connection between the app and the server?

Comment: "secure" is not a binary thing; you need to analyse what are you actually trying to secure and what are you trying to protect it against, if all you want to do is obscure some data, such as a UID, then use a tried and tested hashing mechanism with data duplication on the remote client as well as the server (example: passwords). This is a really wide question and I don't know enough about flutter or your project to advise a direction of travel, however your description feels like it's a standard browser model rather than something like TCP or SSH etc. communcation methods.

Comment: It is only possible to authenticate the user, not the client application. With some effort, it will always be possible for a user to make requests from any client they want including a proxy (Burp, ZAP), Postman, curl, or whatever else. You cannot prevent this, your API must be secure on the server side. Also your user can inspect their id in the first request your app sends, so it is pretty much useless for this purpose.

Comment: @GaborLengyel 1. What do you exactly mean by securing the API on the server side( like examples i'm a bit new to this) 2. Can the user inspect even if the request is a POST request on HTTPS?